# Fail bash script when command expansion fails

Tags: bash, exit-code, command-substitution

I'd like to be able to warn and fail if the following command expansion fails:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -Eeuo pipefail

echo "$(invalid_cmd)"
echo "$?"
```

Instead of failing, I get the following output:

```
./script.sh: line 5: invalid_cmd: command not found

0
```

Comment: Replace `echo "$(invalid_cmd)"` with `invalid_cmd`.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temporary variable. The exit status of variable assignment is the exit status of last command executed - in this case `$(...)`.

```
tmp="$(invalid_cmd)"
ret="$?"  # won't get here, set -e will trigger
echo "$tmp"
echo "$ret"
```

Overall, `echo "$(stuff)"` is just `stuff`. Just run the command, no need to get the to command output to print it, command already prints it.

```
invalid_cmd
echo "$?"
```

Comment: I believe OP was getting the return value of the echo command, not invalid_cmd.

Comment: They were, which is why `set -e` didn't trigger. However, based on the context of their question, that's probably not their intention.

Comment: Ah! I'll be able to use this in the actual problem - I guess I should have provided a more detail. The example above was meant to be the most basic reproduction of my problem. Thanks for inferring the problem. The actual problem is a bit more complicated - I've been using bash as a "no dependency" template engine (probably a bad idea :)). Recently, a template change contained an error and the "template engine" didn't fail the way I'd expected which caused problems downstream. Thanks for the help.